# Logins got crossed in CakePHP 2

Tags: session, php-5.3, cakephp-2.x

I have one huge problem here:

In a CakePHP project, I have a double-step login, where users log-in against the company's Active Directory, and after successful check of credentials, they are checked again on a DB so only specific people can enter the site. The problem is that recently, users can see another user's info as if they entered with another person's credentials. Worst of all is that not in all sections have the same login. Sometimes person A can see himself on page1, but on page2 he can see himself as B, and in page3 he sees himself as C.

But the weirdest of all is that this is not the only project that happens. It appears on another project as well, whom shares the same specs, and the custom Authenticate component (but it crosses only with the own project's users)

I'm a bit lost here, as I checked the cookies sent (only the cake session id) and they are ok and match the session file.

So, any clues what can be the problem here? I don't even know where to begin to look. Could it be on Auth? Or Session? Or Cache?

The platform specs:

- PHP 5.3
- Cakephp 2.5 (not 100% sure but it's around 2.4 and 2.6)
- IIS7
- SQL Server 2014 DB

**EDIT**

Here's my custom authenticate method. Please don't worry about the bad coding of this method, as I had to get it working ASAP (will fix it soon).

```
public function authenticate(CakeRequest $request, CakeResponse $response)
{

    CakeSession::delete('AuthError');
    if($request->data['Usuario']['login'] == '' || $request->data['Usuario']['contraseña'] == '')
    {
        CakeSession::write('AuthError', __("Usuario o contraseña inválidos"));
        return false;
    }
    $datasource = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('active_directory');
    $dominio = isset($request->data['Usuario']['dominio']) ? strtoupper($request->data['Usuario']['dominio']) : 'INTERNAL';
    $host = strtolower($request->data['Usuario']['dominio']).'.'.$datasource->config['host'];   //imsglobal.com
    $port = $datasource->config['port'];

    $enlace = ldap_connect($host, $port);

    $check = @ldap_bind($enlace,$dominio."\\".$request->data['Usuario']['login'],$request->data['Usuario']['contraseña']);
    // debug($check);

    ldap_close($enlace);
    if($check)
    {
        $this->UsuarioModel = ClassRegistry::init('Usuario');
        $usuario = $this->UsuarioModel->obtener_usuarios(array('LOGIN' => $request->data['Usuario']['login']));
        if(!empty($usuario))
        {
            return array('id' => $usuario[0]['id'], 'usuario' => $usuario[0]['usuario']);
        }
        else
        {
            CakeSession::write('AuthError', __("El usuario ingresado no se encuentra registrado en el sistema. Por favor contacte a un administrador"));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        CakeSession::write('AuthError', __("Usuario o contraseña inválidos"));
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Please post some code. (e.g. the controller method for an action producing weird results, your Auth configuration and login method, etc.)

Comment: Have you tried debugging `$this->UsuarioModel->obtener_usuarios(array('LOGIN' => $request->data['Usuario']['login']))` to make sure it holds the `Usuario.id` that matches `Usuario.login`?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that, but when the login got crossed, the variable `$usuario` holds the information of the user that the system thinks it's logged, not the actual one. I've mounted the site on a server with Apache and for now works fine. Probably it's something about IIS, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: That's weird. Are you writing somewhere in your code to `Auth` or `Auth.User` through `CakeSession::write()`?

Comment: Nope, just used once for reading the user from a model through `CakeSession::read('Auth.User.usuario')`, but that's the only time I used it that way

Comment: What about `$this->Auth->login($user)`, is it being called somewhere in your code?

Comment: Just used `$this->Auth->login()` once in `login()` action for standard login, but without any parameters

Comment: I'm running out of ideas. Perhaps you could post more code (e.g. one of the actions misbehaving, any `beforeFilter()` callbacks, your `$components` array, etc.)